# Why can't a function with byref be converted directly to delegate?

Tags: f#, delegates, ref, byref

Under normal circumstances, F# functions can be converted to delegates by calling `new DelegateType` and passing in the function as an argument. But when the delegate contains `byref` parameter, this is not possible directly. For example the code:

```
type ActionByRef<'a> = delegate of 'a byref -> unit

let f (x:double byref) = 
    x <- 6.0

let x = ref 42.0
let d = new ActionByRef<_>(f)
```

won't compile, giving the following error:

> This function value is being used to construct a delegate type whose signature includes a byref argument. You must use an explicit lambda expression taking 1 arguments.

Following the error, modifying the code to use

```
let d = new ActionByRef<_>(fun x -> f(&x))
```

works. But my question is: why is this necessary? Why won't F# allow the conversion from named function to this delegate, but conversion from lambda is fine?

I came upon this behavior when researching [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9077804/41071). I realize `byref` is meant only for compatibility with other .Net languages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the problem is that `byref<'T>` is not an actual type in F# - it looks like a type (to make the language simpler), but it gets compiled to a parameter marked with the `out` flag. This means that `byref<'T>` can be only used in a place where the compiler can actually use the `out` flag.

The problem with function values is that you can construct function e.g. by partial application:

```
let foo (n:int) (b:byref<int>) = 
  b <- n
```

When you pass `foo` as an argument to a delegate constructor, it is a specific case of partial application (with no arguments), but partial application actually needs to construct a new method and then give that to the delegate:

```
type IntRefAction = delegate of byref<int> -> unit  

let ac = IntRefAction(foo 5)
```

The compiler could be clever and generate new method with `byref` parameter (or `out` flag) and then pass that by reference to the actual function, but in general, there will be other compiler-generated method when you don't use the `fun ... -> ...` syntax. Handling this would add complexity and I think that's a relatively rare case, so the F# compiler doesn't do that and asks you to be more explicit...

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think of that. One nitpick, I think `byref` is more like `ref`, not `out`.

Comment: @svick - You're correct - actually, at the IL level, the flag is `ref` and the C# `out` does not exist at all...

Comment: Right, C#'s `out` is actually `ref` plus the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Out` attribute.