# Convert C# delegate to f#

Tags: f#, delegates, c#-to-f#

how do I convert delegate to F#?

**the delegate:**

```
delegate IntPtr HookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

**Edited**

What I'm doing is to do Low Level Keyboard Hook using managed API from c# in F#

Code:

```
[<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)>]
extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(System.IntPtr hhk);

[<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)>]
extern System.IntPtr CallNextHookEx(System.IntPtr hhk, int nCode,System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam);

[<DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)>]
extern System.IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

[<DllImport("user32.dll")>]
extern System.IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int code, HookProc func, System.IntPtr hInstance, int threadID);
```

**Delegate:**

```
type HookProc = delegate of (int * nativeint * nativeint) -> nativeint
```

**Functions**

```
let HookCallback(nCode:int,wParam:System.IntPtr,lParam:System.IntPtr) = 
                    let t = (int)wParam
                    if  t = WM_KEYUP then 
                         let vkCode:int = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam)
                         printfn "%A The Pressed key code is : "  vkCode
                    CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam)



let HookProcF = new HookProc(HookCallback)
let SetHook() = 
                let curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess()
                let curModule = curProcess.MainModule
                let t =0
                let h =  GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName)
                SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, HookProcF, h, t);



let HookMoniter() = 
        let _hookID = SetHook()
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
type HookProc = delegate of int * nativeint * nativeint -> nativeint
```

Note that `nativeint` is just F# name for `IntPtr`

Comment: Yes, this works. This is literally what I am using in one of my projects, other than I am using `nativeint` instead of IntPtr.

Comment: @vcsjones good suggestion, `nativeint` would be more idiomatic here

Comment: @JaredPar It worked but could help me with this error Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': Generic types cannot be marshaled.

Comment: @user12cdhbw7 can you provide some more context for that question?

Comment: Actually, examining this more, this isn't correct. It should be `type HookProc = delegate of int * nativeint * nativeint -> nativeint`. When you include the parenthesis, it creates a delegate of `Tuple<int, IntPtr, IntPtr> -> IntPtr`. The runtime error for marshaling is probably because it's trying to marshal a Tuple, which is a generic type. I overlooked the parens when making my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean call a C# function by delegate with F#?

See the following:

[Using c# delegates with f# functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077804/using-c-sharp-delegates-with-f-functions)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233206.aspx

Comment: I don't think that is what he is asking. It is asking for a literal translation of that C# delegate to F#.

Comment: Just trying to cover the bases.  Jared had already answered the literal translation.