# Uncomptiable paramters type passing to delegate f#

Tags: f#

I'm trying to pass delegate to outer managed API 
the delegate function is:

```
type HookProc = delegate of int * nativeint * nativeint -> nativeint
```

function for delegate:

```
let HookCallback(nCode:int,wParam:System.IntPtr,lParam:System.IntPtr) = 
                    let t = (int)wParam
                    if  t = WM_KEYUP then 
                         let vkCode:int = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam)
                         printfn "%A The Pressed key code is : "  vkCode
                    CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam)
```

the problem I had that when i'm creating delegate

```
let HookProcF = new HookProc(HookCallback)
```

get this error

```
Error   1   Type mismatch. Expecting a     int -> nativeint -> nativeint -> nativeint 
but given a     int * System.IntPtr * nativeint -> System.IntPtr     
The type 'int' does not match the type 'int * System.IntPtr * nativeint'
```

I have asked question related
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691096/convert-c-sharp-delegate-to-f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the error message - when it says `int <> int->nativeint ...`.

You need to use the curried form for the function like so

```
let HookCallback (nCode:int) (wParam:System.IntPtr) (lParam:System.IntPtr) =
```