# c# to f# when 3rd party lib wants a byref as an out parameter

Tags: f#, pass-by-reference, c#-to-f#, byref

I’m trying to convert this method into F#

```
private static bool VerifySignedJwt(ECDsa eCDsa, string token) {
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var claimsPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters {
        ValidIssuer = "me",
        ValidAudience = "you",
        IssuerSigningKey = new ECDsaSecurityKey(eCDsa)
    }, out var parsedToken);
    return claimsPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
}
```

I’m translating this great piece of work by Scott Brady in order to create and validate JWT tokens for a web app, the creation part went without a hitch. On with the Validation part and the reference to a byref required in the JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken method has stumped me.
https://www.scottbrady91.com/C-Sharp/JWT-Signing-using-ECDSA-in-dotnet-Core

If I follow the Microsoft docs below; I get an error saying a “type instantiation involves a byref type. This is not permitted by the rules of Common IL.”
When trying to declare a byref as:

```
let _h (x: byref<'T>) = ()
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/byrefs
I have read the Microsoft docs on byrefs but am left wondering if this relates to .Net core or F#4.5 or does dotnet core supersede all features including byrefs in F#4.5?
Either way I can’t seem to instantiate a SecurityToken at all, the 
"out var parsedToken" is a SecurityToken type, let alone a byref one to use as an output to this 3rd party library, or I can’t seem to declare a byref SecurityToken directly in the call to JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken.

If I use the advice posted in this SO post
[Using c# delegates with f# functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077804/using-c-sharp-delegates-with-f-functions)

```
let function_1 (x:double) (y:double byref) = 
    y <- 6.0
```

I get the same error
“type instantiation involves a byref type. This is not permitted by the rules of Common IL.”

I have used Byrefs before in F# but these were simple integer types and worked without issue.
My project is .Net core 2.1

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Ah using an upcast, so I can’t instantiate SecurityToken directly? And have to upcast something else to this type to achieve that, please someone explain why not? -- let mutable mySecurityToken = JwtSecurityToken("String") :> SecurityToken

Comment: Since the ``out`` parameter in the ``ValidateToken()`` call is the last one, does it work if you simply use a tupled assignment like in the ``Try...()`` functions? Like this:

    ``let claimsPrincipal, parsedToken = tokenHandler.ValidateToken (token, tvp)``

Comment: dumetrulo, thank you. indeed a tuple value works fine but it was the upcast I was misssing, I think, which converted JwtSecurityToken to a SecurityToken type. As my original question was really how to get around having a byref thats a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `out` parameter in the `ValidateToken()` call is the last one, you can simply omit it, and treat it as a second return value:

```
let claimsPrincipal, parsedToken = tokenHandler.ValidateToken (token, tvp)
```

(Here `tvp` would be your `TokenValidationParameters` instance.)

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/parameters-and-arguments#passing-by-reference for more information.

**EDIT:** Since you don't seem to be using the second return value, I figure your function could look as follows:

```
let verifySignedJwt ecdsa token =
    let tokenHandler = JwtSecurityTokenHandler ()
    let tvp = TokenValidationParameters (ValidIssuer = "me",
                                         ValidAudience = "you",
                                         IssuerSigningKey = ECDsaSecurityKey ecdsa)
    let claimsPrincipal, _ = tokenHandler.ValidateToken (token, tvp)
    claimsPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (not necessarily better) would be this:

```
let mutable parsedToken = initialValue

let claimsPrinciple = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, tvp, &parsedToken)

// something with both
```

The above is useful if you have multiple `byref` parameters, or you don't have the pattern of a single `byref` parameter at the very end.